# How to fix footer moving with hyperlinked images

Tags: html, css

[This is the problem I've been having.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxELx.png) I have recently started to learn about web development and have begun making my own mini games website, but i ran into a problem with my footer and hyperlinked images, due to me being new to this i have not been able to figure the issue out despite looking for answers online.

The issue I'm having is that when i add hyperlinked images to the pages where i want the games to be, the footer moves from the bottom of the page to where the images are, as well as this the footer then becomes hyperlinked itself making it a clickable link to one of the pages where a game will be, I'd like to have the images in an aside which will be for 'Recommended Games' with the game itself being in the centre of the page. When i remove the hyperlinked images this problem no longer occurs. Any feedback will be appreciated, Thank You.

HTML

```
    <aside1>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Recommended Games</h1>
        </div>
    </aside1>

    <aside1 id="boxes">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
            <a href="spaceinvader.html">
            <img src="img/spaceinvader.jpg">
            <h3>Space Invaders</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
                <a href="hangman.html">
                <img src="img/hangman.jpg">
                <h3>Hangman</h3>
            </div>
        <div class="box">
                <a href="pacman.html">
                <img src="img/pacman.jpg">
                <h3>Pacman</h3>
            </div>
    </aside1>

    <footer>
        <p>ACI Games, Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
    aside1{
       width:20%;
       position:absolute;
       top:212px;
       bottom:60px;
       left:0px;
       border-left:6px solid;
       border-right:6px solid;
       border-color:aqua
    }

    aside1 h1{
       color:white;
       text-align:center;
    }

    footer{
       position: absolute;
       bottom:0;
       width:100%;
       height:60px;
       background:aqua;
       text-align:center;
       color:white;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to close `</a>` tag.

Here is the updated fiddle:

```html
<aside1>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Recommended Games</h1>
  </div>
</aside1>

<aside1 id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <a href="spaceinvader.html">
        <img src="img/spaceinvader.jpg"></a>
      <h3>Space Invaders</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="hangman.html">
        <img src="img/hangman.jpg"></a>
      <h3>Hangman</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="pacman.html">
        <img src="img/pacman.jpg"></a>
      <h3>Pacman</h3>
    </div>
</aside1>

<footer>
  <p>ACI Games, Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: @Andrew_CI most welcome!!! if this answer works for you then please accept the answer :)